# How to get a random number from 1 to 1000 in iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, random

I have an iPhone application in which I need to give users a new randomly-generated id. How can I generate a random number in the range 1 to 1000?

Comment: At least google first...

Comment: Get a number from zero to 999 and add one.

Comment: @HotLicks can you write some code please

Comment: I could.  You apparently can't.  Which is sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to find random value in iPhone application.

```
int randomValue = (random() % 1000);
NSLog(@"Random Value: %d",randomValue);
```

In general you can find the random numbers for integer only. If you need any more help then let me know.

Comment: This will generate numbers between 0 and 999.

Answer (score 3):

Use this :

```
int randomXAxis =(arc4random() % 1000 ) + 1;
```

Comment: That will give a random number between 0 and 999, inclusive. If you want a number between 1 and 1000, inclusive you'll need to add 1.

Answer (score 1):

type this in your terminal:

```
man arc4random_uniform
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
int rndNumber= (arc4random()%1000)+1; //Generates Number from 1 to 1000.
```

If you want all value once then write above line in For loop